# TemplateDoesNotExist at / at templates/index.html

Tags: python, django

Non the the solutions already posted seem to be working for me.

This is my project directory.

```
.
|-- auto
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- migrations
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- views.py
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|-- mysite
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- test.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- static
|   |-- index.html
`-- templates
    `-- index.html
```

This is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates'),
)
```

I've also tried,

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

This is my views.py

```
def render_landing_page(request, template="templates/index.html"):
    return render(request, template, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.render_landing_page),

]
```

At 127.0.0.1:8000/ I get a "TemplateDoesNotExist at /"

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
templates/index.html
```

But, when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/static/index.html. The page is rendered.

Comment: `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is deprecated since Django 1.8. Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#templates instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `templates/` in your template path, since your telling Django to look inside the dir already through your settings. Also, `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` is deprecated, you just need to return a dict containing your context (an empty dict in your case?):

```
def render_landing_page(request, template="index.html"):
    return render(request, template, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the "templates" prefix.

```
 def render_landing_page(request, template="index.html"):
```

Also, as noted in the comments, TEMPLATE_DIRS has been removed: use the TEMPLATES dictionary.